# Accessing fitted.values when using ddply

Tags: r, plyr, subset, glm

I am using `ddply` to execute `glm` on subsets of my data.  I am having difficulty accessing the estimated Y values.  I am able to get the model parameter estimates using the below code, but all the variations I've tried to get the fitted values have fallen short.  The dependent and independent variables in the `glm` model are column vectors, as is the `"Dmsa"` variable used in the `ddply` operation.

Define the model:

`Model <- function(df){coef(glm(Y~D+O+B+A+log(M), family=poisson(link="log"), data=df))}`

Execute the model on subsets:

`Modrpt <- ddply(msadata, "Dmsa", Model)`

Print `Modrpt` gives the model coefficients, but no Y estimates.

I know that if I wasn't using `ddply`, I can access the `glm` estimated Y values by using the code:

`Model <- glm(Y~D+O+B+A+log(M), family=poisson(link="log"), data=msadata)`

`fits <- Model$fitted.values`

I have tried both of the following to get the fitted values for the subsets, but no luck:

`fits <- fitted.values(ddply(msadata, "Dmsa", Model))`

`fits <- ddply(msadata, "Dmsa", fitted.values(Model))`

I'm sure this is a very easy to code...unfortunately, I'm just learning R.  Does anyone know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Please make the example reproducible by providig some sample data, e.g. `dput( msadata)` or use a built-in dataset like `data(iris)`

Comment: Just replace `coef` by `fitted` in your `Model` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anonymous function in your call to `ddply` e.g.

```
require(plyr)
data(iris)
model <- function(df){
    lm( Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width , data = df )
    }

ddply( iris , "Species" , function(x) fitted.values( model(x) ) )
```

This has the advantage that you can also, without rewriting your `model` function, get the`coef` values by doing

```
    ddply( iris , "Species" , function(x) coef( model(x) ) )
```

As @James points out, this will fall down if you have splits of unequal size, better to use `dlply` which puts the result of each subset in it's own list element.

(*I make no claims for statistical relevance or correctness of the example model - it is just an example*)

Comment: This only works if the splits are of equal size. To use this more generally, use `dlply` instead of `ddply`.

Comment: Simon, I think this is nearly what I need.  Using this code, I am able to get the `coef` version to work (your bottom line of code), but when I use the `fitted.values` code I get the following error: `Error in list_to_dataframe(res, attr(.data, "split_labels")) : 
  Results do not have equal lengths`.  Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: Yes, read James comment above and use `dlply` instead of `ddply`, you have unequal splits in your data (the data.frames that are returned do not have same number of columns)

Comment: Yes, got it to work!  Thank you to James and Simon.  To clarify then, if I have 5 subsets, I should get 5 output lists using `dlply`, correct?  How then would I pull these lists together as vectors where each list is a row vector (i.e., resulting in 5 rows with a column for each observation)?

Comment: Okay, got these lists pulled together as vectors using cbind.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind...since it builds on this.  Ultimately, I'm trying ensure the sum of the estimated Y values for each subset is equal to the sum of the observed Y values.  `cbind` has allowed me to get these lists as row vectors (with two columns), but the Y estimates for each subset are all contained in a single cell for row as `c(1435.234, 8778.1389, ....)`.  Is there a way to get the sum of these estimates within the `cbind` function?  I know I can use `total = sum(model$outlistname)` to get the sum for an individual list, but now sure how to automate that within `cbind`.

Comment: Why would the sum of the estimated be equal to the observed? Do you mean the length? I don't think I understand what you mean. Perhaps a better way is to ask another question? Illustrating with data.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommending doing this in two steps:

```
library(plyr)

# First first the models
models <- dlply(iris, "Species", lm, 
  formula = Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width )

# Next, extract the fitted values
ldply(models, fitted.values)

# Or maybe
ldply(models, as.data.frame(fitted.values))
```