# Appending results of dlply function to original table

Tags: r, plyr, subset

This question builds on the answer that Simon and James provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18082457/2647260)

The `dlply` function worked well to give me Y estimates within my data subsets.  Now, my challenge is getting these Y estimates and residuals back into the original data frame to calculate goodness of fit statistics and for further analysis.

I was able to use `cbind` to convert the `dlply` output lists to row vectors, but this doesn't quite work as the result is (sorry about the poor markdown).

```
model <- function(df){ glm(Y~D+O+A+log(M), family=poisson(link="log"), data=df)}
Modrpt <- ddply(msadata, "Dmsa", function(x)coef(model(x)))
Modest <- cbind(dlply(msadata, "Dmsa", function(x) fitted.values(model(x))))

Subset name | Y_Estimates
-------------------------
Dmsa 1      | c(4353.234, 234.34,...
Dmsa 2      | c(998.234, 2543.55,...
```

This doesn't really answer the mail, because I need to get the individual Y estimates (separated by commas in the Y_estimates column of the `Modest` data frame) into my `msadata` data frame.

Ideally, and I know this is incorrect, but I'll put it here for an example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
msadata$Y_est <- cbind(dlply(msadata, "Dmsa", function(x)fitted.values(model(x))))
```

If I can decompose the list into individual Y estimates, I could join this to my `msadata` data frame by `"Dmsa"`.  I feel like this is very similar to Michael's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18025667/2647260), but something is needed to separate the list elements prior to employing Michael's suggestion of `join()` or `merge()`.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the previous question , I proposed a `data.table` solution. I think it is more appropriate to what you want to do, since you want to apply models by group then aggregate the results with the original data.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
models <- DT[,{
                mod= glm(Y~D+O+A+log(M), family=poisson(link="log"))
                data.frame(res= mod$residuals,
                           fit=mod$fitted.values,
                           mod$model)
               },                          
                by = Dmsa]
```

Here an application with some data:

```
## create some data
set.seed(1)
d.AD <- data.frame(
counts = sample(c(10:30),18,rep=TRUE),
outcome = gl(3,1,18),
treatment = gl(3,6),
type = sample(c(1,2),18,rep=TRUE) ) ## type is the grouping variable
## corece data to a data.table        
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(d.AD)
## apply models
DT[,{mod= glm(formula = counts ~ outcome + treatment, 
                              family = poisson())
               data.frame(res= mod$residuals,
                          fit=mod$fitted.values,
               mod$model)},                          
                     by = type]

   type           res      fit counts outcome treatment
 1:    1 -3.550408e-01 23.25729     15       1         1
 2:    1  2.469211e-01 23.25729     29       1         1
 3:    1  9.866698e-02 25.48543     28       3         1
 4:    1  5.994295e-01 18.13147     29       1         2
 5:    1  4.633974e-16 23.00000     23       2         2
 6:    1  1.576093e-01 19.86853     23       3         2
 7:    1 -3.933199e-01 18.13147     11       1         2
 8:    1 -3.456991e-01 19.86853     13       3         2
 9:    1  6.141856e-02 22.61125     24       1         3
10:    1  4.933908e-02 24.77750     26       3         3
11:    1 -1.154845e-01 22.61125     20       1         3
12:    2  9.229985e-02 15.56349     17       1         1
13:    2  5.805515e-03 21.87302     22       2         1
14:    2 -1.004589e-01 15.56349     14       1         1
15:    2  2.537653e-16 14.00000     14       1         2
16:    2 -1.603110e-01 21.43651     18       1         3
17:    2  1.662347e-01 21.43651     25       1         3
18:    2 -4.214963e-03 30.12698     30       2         3
```

Comment: Wow, that is quite awesome AGSTUDY!  I never would have figured that out, but it worked perfectly.  The result is exactly what I need.  Kudos!